# How to get base url from php server to an android app

Tags: android

Is there any way to get base URL from php Server to an Android app ?
I have hard coded the base URL in the application, but now i want to change the server name with out uninstall the existing App. Is there any possibility to get base URL from the php Server  to the Android Application

Comment: You mean with the current app? No, if you haven't implemented such a feature currently.

Comment: Do you literally mean "uninstall"? You could upload a new version and do the change with an app upgrade.

Comment: I concur with @Henry on this one. You could have changed it using a silent push notification provided the required code was already in place. Since its not, you cannot. 

However, if your application supports redirects, you could write code on the server to redirect requests from old domain to the new one using 307/301 HTTP status codes.

Comment: i just wanted to change the server name without affecting the existing android application. Is it possible to get base URL from the php server

Comment: Try it with `firebase cloud messaging`. You can send data and store it in your app

Comment: if you have fix the value in variable then you have to update the app and for future you can use Firebase Remote Config

Answer (score 0):

There is no way if your current published version has been released and it does not yet prepare for this.

However, for the later version, you can rely on [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) to change your server API on the fly. When your application start, it will load the default URL from your hard coding, then try to request your current config from the Firebase. From this point, when you change the config from Firebase, the application would update the configuration automatically.